# How to remove all records from attribute table with repeating values in sql?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a "pedestrian"(PED) and "vehicle"(VEHICLE) crash tables. On performing inner join ie

```
select * 
from ped 
inner join vehicle on ped.CRSH_NUM = vehicle.CRSH_NUM ;
```

I am getting duplicate values in join result

```
CRSH_NUM    CAL_YR PER_SQ   xyz  xyz       xyz  xyz xyz xyz
-------------------------------------------------------------------
124035430   2015       2    FL  32148       086 2   4   1
127226060   2015       1    FL  33755       054 1   3   3
704850370   2015       2    FL  33406       024 2   1   7
704850370   2015       2    FL  33406       024 2   1   7
708287950   2015       3    FL  32724       059 1   1   7
708287950   2015       2    FL  32724       060 1   1   7
734803610   2015       2    FL  32724       043 1   2   3
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The result that I want is :

```
CRSH_NUM    CAL_YR PER_SQ   xyz  xyz       xyz  xyz xyz xyz
-------------------------------------------------------------------
124035430   2015       2    FL  32148       086 2   4   1
127226060   2015       1    FL  33755       054 1   3   3
734803610   2015       2    FL  32724       043 1   2   3
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Also, I removed other attributes since they wont fit here. By this I mean that the query I will run need to select all columns ie

`select *` rather than `select CRSH_NUM, CAL_YR , PER_SQ, xyz..... from tablename`.

I am using sql developer and oracle 12c server.

Comment: What database are you actually using MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?  Please tag properly.

Comment: These aren't duplicates.  These records exists because other data is relevant and unique (provided you are joining on the PK/FK relationship) 704850370 is repeating because either ped or vehicle list crash_num multiple times.  your column headers xyz xyz,xyz don't help isolate the issue other than to say column 6 labeled XYZ in your results shows that the values are not duplicates.  Although the 1st and 2nd record appear to be identical (though you could have removed the data making them unique) Why is 704850370 not in your expected results? nor is 708287950?

Comment: Are you sure you're joining on the PK/FK relationship?

Comment: @xQbert My only request is to delete duplicate/repeating values from column "CRSH_NUM" . If you want to look at bigger picture, each pedestrian crash having more than 1 vehicle involved has several rows, where each row represent individual vehicle. So , I want to remove all crashes involving either 1 pedestrian and several vehicles or 1 vehicle and several vehicles.

Comment: So what determines what values are used in each of the other columns?  you could use max/min on each column or apply a row number to each and only show where row_number() = 1...

Answer (score 0):

if you want all the record not related  to duplicated  crash_num  you can use group by,  having and not in

```
  select * 
  from ped 
  inner join vehicle on ped.CRSH_NUM = vehicle.CRSH_NUM 
  where crsh_num not in (
        select CRSH_NUM    
        from ped 
        inner join vehicle on ped.CRSH_NUM = vehicle.CRSH_NUM 
        group by CRSH_NUM
        having count(*)>1;
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

After comments, maybe just assign a row  number starting at 1 incresing for each cras_num and then only show rows #'s that are 1? the order by determines which reocords and values are displayed since they are different.

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT *, row_number() over (partition by CRSH_NUM order by Cal_year Desc Per_SEQ Desc) RN
             FROM ped 
             INNER join vehicle 
                on ped.CRSH_NUM = vehicle.CRSH_NUM

Select * from cte where RN = 1
```